# Reading a records file and create a index for it

Tags: java, file, records

So I need to read from a records file where '#' determines the end of a record and '|' the end of a field like this: #9783642217074|Interaction|Macie|Furtado,Elizabeth|Winckler,Marco|2011#.

Then I need to write just the first field of each record in another file.
I'm trying to use Java I/O RandomAccessFile but I really need some light to figure it out.
If anyone could tell what methods or the ideia behind this Ill be thankful.

Comment: Well, read the file line by line and parse the strings. Or, if the records might span lines read multiple lines (or the entire file) and then parse.

Comment: If the input is a text file, and the records are delimited (as opposed to having a fixed size) you don't need `RandomAccessFile` - reading the file line character-by-character would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `RandomAccessFile`, you would be fine with reading and writing your files character-by-character.

Your program can be in any of these three states:

1. Waiting for the start of the next record
2. Writing the content of the first field
3. Waiting for the end of the record

The program changes its state as follows:

- Initially, it is in the state number `1`
- When `#` character is detected in state `1`, the state becomes `2`
- When `|` is detected in state `2`, the state becomes `3`
- When `#` is detected in state `3`, the state becomes `1`.
- Each character received in state `2` is duplicated into the output file
- When the state transitions from `3` to `1`, write a separator into the output.

This should be really straightforward to code with a single loop that reads from a file, and a handful of `if`-`then`-`else` statements. Make a variable called `state` outside the loop, set it to `1`, open the input and the output files, and make a loop to read the input character-by-character until the end of the file is reached.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation using the Scanner class.

Main.class

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // The path of the project
        String basePath = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
        // The path of the record file, in relevance to <basePath>
        String recordPath = basePath.concat("/RecordList.txt");
        // Make sure that path is correct
        System.out.println(recordPath + "\n");

        // Store all Record objects in an array
        ArrayList<Record> recordArray = new ArrayList<Record>();

        // Lets try to read the file, and parse each line at a time
        try {
            // input the file content to the String "input"
            BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(recordPath));

            // Store every line of <file> in <input> String
            String line;
            String input = "";
            while ((line = file.readLine()) != null) {
                input += line + '\n';
                // Remove the # symbols at beginning and end
                line = line.replaceFirst("#", "");
                System.out.println(line);

                //
                String recordData[] = line.split("[|]");
                Record record = new Record(recordData);
                recordArray.add(record);
            }
            // Make sure to close the <file>
            file.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println();

        //Verify results
        for (Record record : recordArray) {
            System.out.println(record.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Record.class

```
public class Record {
        // #9783642217074|Interaction|Macie|Furtado,Elizabeth|Winckler,Marco|2011#
        private String id;
        private String field2;
        private String field3;
        private String field4;
        private String field5;
        private String year;

        public Record(String[] recordData) {
            this.id = recordData[0];
            this.field2 = recordData[1];
            this.field3 = recordData[2];
            this.field4 = recordData[3];
            this.field5 = recordData[4];
            this.year = recordData[5];
        }

        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
         */
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Record [id=" + id + ", field2=" + field2 + ", field3="
                    + field3 + ", field4=" + field4 + ", field5=" + field5
                    + ", year=" + year + "]";
        }

    }
```

And here is the RecordFile.txt I generated (mind the data I made up)

```
#9783642217074|Interaction|Macie|Furtado,Elizabeth|Winckler,Marco|2011#
#9783612343243|Interaction|Freddie|Fuder,Franscon|Winner,Marie|2013#
#9213432423534|Interaction|Jimbo|Furtado,Melo|Yakasabi,Johnson|2001#
```

*As always, please use my code as a reference. It is always better to learn how to write code yourself, especially when this question pertains to a homework assignment.*

Comment: Please note that posting a ready-made solution to a problem that he was intended for the posters is generally a disservice to them and to their teachers. Giving hints or providing key insights into the problem would be fine, but the solution should be theirs, not someone else's.